# I can not boot my VHDX which was created from physical drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, vhdx

I need to migrate my Server 2012 R2 Fileserver (physical) to another Server (virtual). That's why I need to create VHDX Files to run them later in Hyper-V

All my drives were no problem, except the C Drive.

Whenever I boot the created C Drive, I get this error:

[image: Error Screenshot Hyper-V]

If I simply open the VHDX on my filesystem, or on any server, I get the following error which says `you need to format the F: Drive before you can use it`:

[image: Error F: drive]

As you can see, the VHDX strangely contains 2 drives, and one of them (F:) is not formatted. that's why I can't use the VHDX file, because it does not recognize this drive I guess. I guess this is where EFI is located.

I tried to create the VHDX in 3 different ways. For the first two ways I tried [Disk2VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd)

like this (I tried it with the `\\?\volume` and without the `\\?\volume` partition):

[image: Disk2VHD Screenshot]

The third way I tried is directly from Hyper-V where I could say I wanted to create a VHDX from a physical drive.

[image: Hyper-V wizard]

but all of them get the same end result, the corrupted VHDX.

I read somewhere that I need to `mountvol x: /s` first to make my EFI Partition visible for disk2vhd, but `mountvol` does not seem to have a `/s` anymore?

How can I get a working VHDX? Thanks

Comment: A generic step, but can you boot on the install media to do a bootrec /fixboot ? or even bootrec /RebuildBcd

Comment: @yagmoth555 you mean start the newly created machine with an WindowsServer.iso and the C-drive attached?

Comment: Yes It's what I meant

Comment: @yagmoth555 in diskpart, I see that the "onknown" volume is the C:\ drive, and the actual C drive is E. I guess if I could change them it should work. but diskpart does not save the changes.... trying to do a bootrec....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `bootrec /fixboot` or `bootrec /rebuildbcd` while booting the VM with the disk attached, but to write a bit more for my tip in your case, as I seen your C drive is actually the E drive, check `bcdedit` please too;

Boot the virtual machine from the correct Microsoft Windows installation media (Correct architecture and version of the operating system).
Select the appropriate keyboard layout and language options and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
Click Repair your computer.
Select the operating system to be repaired and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
Click Start > Run, type cmd and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Type `bcdedit` and press Enter.
Under the Windows Boot Manager title with the identifier set to `{bootmgr}`, you may see that the device is set to boot. Similarly, under the Windows Boot Loader with the identifier set to `{default}`, you may see that the device and osdevice are set to boot. These items should be set properly for your environment. Usually these appear as `partition=C:`. In some cases the `{default}` identifier may have them set to `partition=E:`.

Run these commands to correct the configuration:

**Note**: `bcdedit` is located in this path: `c:\windows\system32`.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:

bcdedit /set {default} device partition=C:

bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=C:
```

Type exit at the command prompt and select Shutdown. The reconfigure should now complete successfully. If it fails again, repeat Steps 1 to 7 and then run these commands to set the default device to `partition=E:`

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:

bcdedit /set {default} device partition=E:

bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=E:
```

Comment: I did it slightly different, with `DISKPART` i removed the letter from the C-drive `remove letter=C` then assign letter=C to the E-drive, then `bootrec /RebuildBcD` and I had to change Generation 2 VM to Generation 1 for it to work